# NEST (ElasticSearch) Terms Aggregation does not acknowledge the Query

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a search request as below:

```
            var response = client.Search<ProductElastic>(s => s

                .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Should(mu => mu
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.title)
                                    .Boost(1.5)
                                    .Query(inputfilter.q)
                                ), mu => mu
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.content)
                                    .Query(inputfilter.q)
                                )
                            )

                        )
                    )

                 .Aggregations(a => a
                        .Terms("doctype_i", he => he
                            .Field(g => g.doctype_i)
                        )
                        .Terms("category_i", e => e
                            .Field(ge => ge.category_i)
                            .Size(100)
                        )
                    )

            );
```

`inputfilter.q` holds the search term. When `inputfilter.q` is null it returns all the results and my aggregation bucket numbers are accurately represented. When `inputfilter.q` is defined (ex. searching for "test") it refines the results set, however, my aggregation buckets still give me the full numbers as before, as if nothing was searched for. For the record, `doctype_i` and `category_i` are integer type fields in Elastic.

How do I make my `.Aggregations` acknowledge the `.Query` so the aggregation buckets reflect numbers based on the results set?

Comment: Your query should work. Aggregations result should be for the documents returned. Can you add docs(sample matching and not matching query) and result , to reproduce this issue

Comment: Agreed. 

I just discovered the issue is a result of using .Should , which gives the aggregations the right to ignore the query. When I use .Must coupled with the binary || operator, then it has to take the query into consideration.